# Error TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Item'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to compile an open source project to my local angular, it throws the following error

> ERROR in src/app/blu_src/items/item.ts(111,29): error TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Item'.
>     Type 'Item' is not assignable to type 'Item'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
>       Types have separate declarations of a private property 'scene'.

Typescript version :  2.7.2

The code is:

scene.ts

```
   public removeItem(item: Item, dontRemove?: boolean) {
      dontRemove = dontRemove || false;
      // use this for item meshes
      this.itemRemovedCallbacks.fire(item);
      item.removed();
      this.scene.remove(item);
      if (!dontRemove) {
        Utils.removeValue(this.items, item);
      }
    }
```

item.ts

```
private scene: Scene;

   public remove() {
      this.scene.removeItem(this);
    };
```

Actual Code is:

item.ts

```
 import * as THREE from 'three';
import {Utils} from "../core/utils"; 
import {Model} from "../model/model";
import {Metadata} from "../items/metadata";
import {Scene} from "../model/scene";

  /**
   * An Item is an abstract entity for all things placed in the scene,
   * e.g. at walls or on the floor.
   */
  export abstract class Item extends THREE.Mesh {

    /** */
    private scene: Scene;

    /** */
    private errorGlow = new THREE.Mesh();

    /** */
    private hover = false;

    /** */
    private selected = false;

    /** */
    private highlighted = false;

    /** */
    private error = false;

    /** */
    private emissiveColor = 0x444444;

    /** */
    private errorColor = 0xff0000;

    /** */
    private resizable: boolean;

    /** Does this object affect other floor items */
    protected obstructFloorMoves = true;

    /** */
    protected position_set: boolean;

    /** Show rotate option in context menu */
    protected allowRotate = true;

    /** */
    public fixed = false;

    /** dragging */
    private dragOffset = new THREE.Vector3();

    /** */
    protected halfSize: THREE.Vector3;
    geometry:any;
    material:any;
    castShadow:any;
    receiveShadow:any;
    position:any;
    rotation:any;
    scale:any;


    constructor(protected model: Model, public metadata: Metadata, geometry: THREE.Geometry, material: THREE.MeshFaceMaterial, position: THREE.Vector3, rotation: number, scale: THREE.Vector3) {
      super();

      this.scene = this.model.scene;
      this.geometry = geometry;
      this.material = material;

      this.errorColor = 0xff0000;

      this.resizable = metadata.resizable;

      this.castShadow = true;
      this.receiveShadow = false;

      this.geometry = geometry;
      this.material = material;

      if (position) {
        this.position.copy(position);
        this.position_set = true;
      } else {
        this.position_set = false;
      }

      // center in its boundingbox
      this.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
      this.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(
        - 0.5 * (this.geometry.boundingBox.max.x + this.geometry.boundingBox.min.x),
        - 0.5 * (this.geometry.boundingBox.max.y + this.geometry.boundingBox.min.y),
        - 0.5 * (this.geometry.boundingBox.max.z + this.geometry.boundingBox.min.z)
      ));
      this.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
      this.halfSize = this.objectHalfSize();

      if (rotation) {
        this.rotation.y = rotation;
      }

      if (scale != null) {
        this.setScale(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);
      }
    };

    /** */
    public remove() {
      this.scene.removeItem(this);
    };

    /** */
    public resize(height: number, width: number, depth: number) {
      var x = width / this.getWidth();
      var y = height / this.getHeight();
      var z = depth / this.getDepth();
      this.setScale(x, y, z);
    }

    /** */
    public setScale(x: number, y: number, z: number) {
      var scaleVec = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
      this.halfSize.multiply(scaleVec);
      scaleVec.multiply(this.scale)
      this.scale.set(scaleVec.x, scaleVec.y, scaleVec.z);
      this.resized();
      this.scene.needsUpdate = true;
    };

    /** */
    public setFixed(fixed: boolean) {
      this.fixed = fixed;
    }

    /** Subclass can define to take action after a resize. */
    protected abstract resized();

    /** */
    public getHeight = function () {
      return this.halfSize.y * 2.0;
    }

    /** */
    public getWidth = function () {
      return this.halfSize.x * 2.0;
    }

    /** */
    public getDepth = function () {
      return this.halfSize.z * 2.0;
    }

    /** */
    public abstract placeInRoom();

    /** */
    public initObject = function () {
      this.placeInRoom();
      // select and stuff
      this.scene.needsUpdate = true;
    };

    /** */
    public removed() {
    }

    /** on is a bool */
    public updateHighlight() {
      var on = this.hover || this.selected;
      this.highlighted = on;
      var hex = on ? this.emissiveColor : 0x000000;
      console.log("printing the this.material",this.material);
      (<THREE.MeshFaceMaterial>this.material).forEach((material) => {
        // TODO_Ekki emissive doesn't exist anymore?
        (<any>material).emissive.setHex(hex);
      });
    }

    /** */
    public mouseOver() {
      this.hover = true;
      this.updateHighlight();
    };

    /** */
    public mouseOff() {
      this.hover = false;
      this.updateHighlight();
    };

    /** */
    public setSelected() {
      this.selected = true;
      this.updateHighlight();
    };

    /** */
    public setUnselected() {
      this.selected = false;
      this.updateHighlight();
    };

    /** intersection has attributes point (vec3) and object (THREE.Mesh) */
    public clickPressed(intersection) {
      this.dragOffset.copy(intersection.point).sub(this.position);
    };

    /** */
    public clickDragged(intersection) {
      if (intersection) {
        this.moveToPosition(
          intersection.point.sub(this.dragOffset),
          intersection);
      }
    };

    /** */
    public rotate(intersection) {
      if (intersection) {
        var angle = Utils.angle(
          0,
          1,
          intersection.point.x - this.position.x,
          intersection.point.z - this.position.z);

        var snapTolerance = Math.PI / 16.0;

        // snap to intervals near Math.PI/2
        for (var i = -4; i <= 4; i++) {
          if (Math.abs(angle - (i * (Math.PI / 2))) < snapTolerance) {
            angle = i * (Math.PI / 2);
            break;
          }
        }

        this.rotation.y = angle;
      }
    }

    /** */
    public moveToPosition(vec3, intersection) {
      this.position.copy(vec3);
    }

    /** */
    public clickReleased() {
      if (this.error) {
        this.hideError();
      }
    };

    /**
     * Returns an array of planes to use other than the ground plane
     * for passing intersection to clickPressed and clickDragged
     */
    public customIntersectionPlanes() {
      return [];
    }

    /** 
     * returns the 2d corners of the bounding polygon
     * 
     * offset is Vector3 (used for getting corners of object at a new position)
     * 
     * TODO: handle rotated objects better!
     */
    public getCorners(xDim, yDim, position) {

      position = position || this.position;

      var halfSize = this.halfSize.clone();

      var c1 = new THREE.Vector3(-halfSize.x, 0, -halfSize.z);
      var c2 = new THREE.Vector3(halfSize.x, 0, -halfSize.z);
      var c3 = new THREE.Vector3(halfSize.x, 0, halfSize.z);
      var c4 = new THREE.Vector3(-halfSize.x, 0, halfSize.z);

      var transform = new THREE.Matrix4();
      //console.log(this.rotation.y);
      transform.makeRotationY(this.rotation.y); //  + Math.PI/2)

      c1.applyMatrix4(transform);
      c2.applyMatrix4(transform);
      c3.applyMatrix4(transform);
      c4.applyMatrix4(transform);

      c1.add(position);
      c2.add(position);
      c3.add(position);
      c4.add(position);

      //halfSize.applyMatrix4(transform);

      //var min = position.clone().sub(halfSize);
      //var max = position.clone().add(halfSize);

      var corners = [
        { x: c1.x, y: c1.z },
        { x: c2.x, y: c2.z },
        { x: c3.x, y: c3.z },
        { x: c4.x, y: c4.z }
      ];

      return corners;
    }

    /** */
    public abstract isValidPosition(vec3): boolean;

    /** */
    public showError(vec3) {
      vec3 = vec3 || this.position;
      if (!this.error) {
        this.error = true;
        this.errorGlow = this.createGlow(this.errorColor, 0.8, true);
        this.scene.add(this.errorGlow);
      }
      this.errorGlow.position.copy(vec3);
    }

    /** */
    public hideError() {
      if (this.error) {
        this.error = false;
        this.scene.remove(this.errorGlow);
      }
    }

    /** */
    private objectHalfSize(): THREE.Vector3 {
      var objectBox = new THREE.Box3();
      objectBox.setFromObject(this);
      return objectBox.max.clone().sub(objectBox.min).divideScalar(2);
    }

    /** */
    public createGlow(color, opacity, ignoreDepth): THREE.Mesh {
      ignoreDepth = ignoreDepth || false
      opacity = opacity || 0.2;
      var glowMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: color,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        opacity: 0.2,
        transparent: true,
        depthTest: !ignoreDepth
      });

      var glow = new THREE.Mesh(<THREE.Geometry>this.geometry.clone(), glowMaterial);
      glow.position.copy(this.position);
      glow.rotation.copy(this.rotation);
      glow.scale.copy(this.scale);
      return glow;
    };
  }
```

scene.ts

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {Utils} from "../core/utils";
import {Item} from "../Items/item";
import {Factory} from "../items/factory";
import {Model} from "../model/model";
declare var $: any;


  /**
   * The Scene is a manager of Items and also links to a ThreeJS scene.
   */
  export class Scene {

    /** The associated ThreeJS scene. */
    private scene: THREE.Scene;

    /** */
    private items: Item[] = [];

    /** */
    public needsUpdate = false;

    /** The Json loader. */
    private loader: THREE.JSONLoader;

    /** */
    private itemLoadingCallbacks = $.Callbacks();

    /** Item */
    private itemLoadedCallbacks = $.Callbacks();

    /** Item */
    private itemRemovedCallbacks = $.Callbacks();

    /**
     * Constructs a scene.
     * @param model The associated model.
     * @param textureDir The directory from which to load the textures.
     */
    constructor(private model: Model, private textureDir: string) {
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

      // init item loader
      this.loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
      this.loader.crossOrigin = "";
    }

    /** Adds a non-item, basically a mesh, to the scene.
     * @param mesh The mesh to be added.
     */
    public add(mesh: THREE.Mesh) {
      this.scene.add(mesh);
    }

    /** Removes a non-item, basically a mesh, from the scene.
     * @param mesh The mesh to be removed.
     */
    public remove(mesh: THREE.Mesh) {
      this.scene.remove(mesh);
      Utils.removeValue(this.items, mesh);
    }

    /** Gets the scene.
     * @returns The scene.
     */
    public getScene(): THREE.Scene {
      return this.scene;
    }

    /** Gets the items.
     * @returns The items.
     */
    public getItems(): Item[] {
      return this.items;
    }

    /** Gets the count of items.
     * @returns The count.
     */
    public itemCount(): number {
      return this.items.length
    }

    /** Removes all items. */
    public clearItems() {
      var items_copy = this.items
      var scope = this;
      this.items.forEach((item) => {
        scope.removeItem(item, true);
      });
      this.items = []
    }

    /**
     * Removes an item.
     * @param item The item to be removed.
     * @param dontRemove If not set, also remove the item from the items list.
     */
    public removeItem(item: Item, dontRemove?: boolean) {
      dontRemove = dontRemove || false;
      // use this for item meshes
      this.itemRemovedCallbacks.fire(item);
      item.removed();
      this.scene.remove(item);
      if (!dontRemove) {
        Utils.removeValue(this.items, item);
      }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an item and adds it to the scene.
     * @param itemType The type of the item given by an enumerator.
     * @param fileName The name of the file to load.
     * @param metadata TODO
     * @param position The initial position.
     * @param rotation The initial rotation around the y axis.
     * @param scale The initial scaling.
     * @param fixed True if fixed.
     */
    public addItem(itemType: number, fileName: string, metadata, position: THREE.Vector3, rotation: number, scale: THREE.Vector3, fixed: boolean) {
      itemType = itemType || 1;
      var scope = this;
      var loaderCallback = function (geometry: THREE.Geometry, materials: THREE.Material[]) {
        var item = new (Factory.getClass(itemType))(
          scope.model,
          metadata, geometry,
          new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials),
          position, rotation, scale
        );
        item.fixed = fixed || false;
        scope.items.push(item);
        scope.add(item);
        item.initObject();
        scope.itemLoadedCallbacks.fire(item);
      }

      this.itemLoadingCallbacks.fire();
      this.loader.load(
        fileName,
        loaderCallback,
        undefined // TODO_Ekki 
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please add the complete code for scene.ts and item.ts

Comment: scene is a private property of `item.ts` and you are trying to access it in the `scene.ts`.

Comment: added @SiddAjmera

Comment: check the whole code now @jai

Comment: In which file you are getting the error.  please post the complete error and create minimum reproduction on stackblitz if possible

Comment: edited with path check the error now @SachinGupta

Comment: Is this some kind of circular dependency issue?  I can't reproduce this problem on my environment using TS3.2.  If you can reproduce on stackblitz or the like, that would be helpful.  If you can't, then you know you have some issue in your local environment that you need to resolve.  In either case, it is worth your time to try to make a [mcve].